# set default page to Particular store view

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url-rewrite, store-view

I have to store view under a store whose code as `default` and `crescent`

when I run the domain name it should be pointing to `default` store and when I run URL as `http://hostname/crescent` it should pointing to `crescent` store

for example

`http://localhost:81/ecommerce/` Should point to `http://localhost:81/ecommerce/?___store=default`

`http://localhost:81/ecommerce/crescent` Should point to `http://localhost:81/ecommerce/?___store=crescent`

To achieve this, I tried below

Under URL rewrite management I created a custom rule as below

Request Path: /

Target Path: ?___store=default

Redirect: Permanent

But no luck,

can someone suggest me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this either through server configuration (nginx/Apache) or through setting a `$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']` in `index.php`.

The latter would require creating a directory `crescent` in `MAGENTO_ROOT`, copying `index.php` to it and assigning a proper store code to be run there - in your case it would be `crescent`.

I'm assuming your `MAGENTO_ROOT` is inside `/ecommerce/` directory (where your main index.php is placed).

Example of directory structure and index.php/.htaccess:

```
-- ecommerce
    |-- crescent
        | -- index.php (described below)
        | -- .htaccess (described below)
    |-- index.php
```

The content of index.php inside crescent would look something like this:

```
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = 'crescent';
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = 'store';
```

URL Rewrites are used to rewrite entirely different things.

This solution with a separate directory also allows you to make a translation/separate design for error pages.

You could also use .htaccess for this where based on the URL you could do something similar to this which's based on domains:

```
SetEnvIf Host .*.pl* MAGE_RUN_CODE=crescent
SetEnvIf Host .*.pl* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

but you're sure that the store in `/crescent/` should be that one so you can do this:

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE=crescent
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```